# How to set up OpenSSL so I can send mail with PHP vis Gmail SMTP?

Tags: php, ssl, iis-6, smtp, gmail

I have been sat solid looking for the answer to this question, I have tried many techniques and I just cannot get this to work.

I am using the PHP Mailer libraries to send an email through Gmail SMTP server, I am using PHP 4 with iis6 on a windows 2003 box.

This is the error I am given:

Strict Standards: date() [function.date]: It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. Please use the date.timezone setting, the TZ environment variable or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected 'Europe/London' for '1.0/DST' instead in E:\ltuweb\36Hours\phpmailer\class.phpmailer.php  on line 1612

Strict Standards: date() [function.date]: It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. Please use the date.timezone setting, the TZ environment variable or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected 'Europe/London' for '1.0/DST' instead in E:\ltuweb\36Hours\phpmailer\class.phpmailer.php on line 1616

Warning: fsockopen() [function.fsockopen]: unable to connect to ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465 (Unable to find the socket transport "ssl" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?) in E:\ltuweb\36Hours\phpmailer\class.smtp.php on line 122
Message was not sent
Mailer Error: SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.

Please can someone help me fix this, thank you in advance!

Ash

--------------- UPDATE! ----------------

I cannot see when I type in phpinfo(); a heading that says OpenSSL enabled, how do i address this issue because it is definitely uncommented in my php.ini file.

--------------- UPDATE! ----------------

It appears to have been our firewall etc that was blocking the ssl properly, grrrr dam cisco. Thanks everyone!

Thank you!

Comment: Check out class.mailer.php a class setup to handle smtp and what not, easy to use and once you have ssl as below answer suggests this class should be trivial to use.  Just google "class.mailer.php" and you will find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you install PHP with OpenSSL support, as described here? http://php.net/manual/en/openssl.installation.php

Comment: I have already tried installing this, I just tried again. How and where do i reference to these files properly? Because i don't see where they are being called and can't work it out.

Comment: You most certainly need to install OpenSSL and its development header first.